# Bash Bug? Getting STDOUT from two process substitutions

Tags: bash

For a specific shell script, I need a functionality like in this simplified example:

```
{ replies=`echo output > >(cat >&3; echo reply1) 2> >(cat >&2; echo reply2)` ;} 3>&1
```

Obivously, I would like `$replies` to be something like `reply1 reply2`, but the "second" stream never gets into the variable but comes out at STDOUT:

```
output
reply2
$ echo $replies 
reply1
```

It this a bug or a restriction, and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swapping the order of redirections fixes the "problem":

```
$ { replies=$(echo output  2> >(cat >&2; echo reply2) > >(cat >&3; echo reply1)); } 3>&1
output
$ echo $replies
reply1 reply2
```

The "problem" in your example is that when `cat >&2; echo reply2` is executed the standard output is already redirected to `>(cat >&3; echo reply1)`. As a result the output of `echo reply2` goes to `cat >&3`.

Comment: I actually thought that I tested that some time ago and that it did not work ... but obviously I'm wrong, it works fine for me. Thank you also for the explanation, I even understand now why this is so.